# What do they mean by this: "the definition of product topo shows that this mapping is continuous"

Tags: abstract-algebra, continuity, p-adic-number-theory

Let $\Bbb{Z}_2$ be the $2$-adic integers.  There's a bijection

$\psi : \Bbb{Z}_2 \to C$, the Cantor set, defined by $\psi (\sum_{i \geq 0} a_i p^i) = \sum_{i \geq 0} \dfrac{2a_i}{3^{i+1}}$.  The text then says that, and I quote,

> The definition of the product topology shows that this mapping is continuous, and 
>   hence is a homeomorphism, since the spaces in question are compact.

How do they get that, with respect to *what* product topology?  Thanks.

Comment: The product topology on $\left(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\right)^\mathbb{N}$. Which $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is homeomorphic to (by definition of the topology on $\mathbb{Z}_2$).

Comment: Thanks I'll have to re-go over the last section

Comment: If the "last section" did not show that the metric for $\mathbb Z_2$ induces the product topology, then that book needs an editor.

Comment: It did, but not very well.  And sometimes I don't go through material as thoroughy as I should.  That is a a pro / con of studying on your own I guess.  I want to see these fractal objects related to $p$-adic numbers so I must study this one more!